# How to set SSL to no ssl for FTP server in windows 2019

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis, ftp

I'm trying to prepare script to configure FTP server on Windows. 
I need to SSL setting to No SSL using powershell.

[image: img1]

By default SSL is set to Require. I've created a FTP site but when i try to access it i'm getting error. Is that due to SSL?

[image: img2]

Also configuration is not found.

[image: img3]

Comment: So are you asking how to turn off SSL? Or how to fix the "User cannot log in" problem (which does not seem to be related to SSL)? We need your current PowerShell code in any case.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/editing-collections-with-configuration-editor Use configuration editor to generate PowerShell scripts.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. Also make sure to add all relevant information *as text* inside your question, not as inlined images or outside links. And, of course, obviously DO NOT DISABLE TLS.

Comment: New-WebFtpSite -Name $FTPSiteName -Port $FTPPort -PhysicalPath $FTPRootDir -IPAddress $ip
$FTPSitePath = "IIS:\Sites\$FTPSiteName"
$BasicAuth = 'ftpServer.security.authentication.basicAuthentication.enabled'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $FTPSitePath -Name $BasicAuth -Value $True
$Param = @{
    Filter   = "/system.ftpServer/security/authorization"
    Value    = @{
        accessType  = "Allow"
        roles  = ""
 users = "*"
        permissions = 1
    }
    PSPath   = 'IIS:\'
    Location = $FTPSiteName
}Add-WebConfiguration @param
Restart-WebItem "IIS:\Sites\$FTPSiteName" -Verbose

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes i need to turn off SSL. I tried creating FTP site manually with No SSL and i'm able to login without any issues. The issue is only with script created FTP site. Am I missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error could probably caused by the corrupted configuration.  I suggest you roll back configuration and try the powershell script below.

Set IIS FTP SSL to NO SSL equal to set 'require SSL' to 'allow SSL' and remove 'certificate hash'.
So you have to set both

**system.applicationHost/sites /[name='Site Name'].ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy and system.applicationHost/sites /[name='Site Name'].ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy**

Please try this

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='MYFTP']/ftpServer/security/ssl" -name "serverCertHash" -value ""

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='MYFTP']/ftpServer/security/ssl" -name "controlChannelPolicy" -value "SslAllow"

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='MYFTP']/ftpServer/security/ssl" -name "dataChannelPolicy" -value "SslAllow"
```

Comment: I changed SSL to allow with certhash value null. It worked fine.

Comment: $ssl = @(
'ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy',
'ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy',
'ftpServer.security.ssl.serverCertHash'
)
Set-ItemProperty -Path $FTPsitepath -Name $ssl[0] -Value $false
Set-ItemProperty -Path $FTPsitepath -Name $ssl[1] -Value $false
Set-ItemProperty -Path $FTPsitepath -Name $ssl[2] -Value ""
Regarding user cannot login error, "New-WebFtpSite" cmdlet is not accepting the -Physicalpath. I created virtual directory and set it as physicalpath. Thanks everyone for your help.